# Accessing static field from Class<A> variable

Tags: java, class, static

I have the following situation (I know it doesn't sound real but I simplified it for better understanding):

- A `class A`, with a `public static int f;` declared
- Other classes `B, C, D, ...`  that extend A
- A method `foo` (somewhere else, doesn't matter) with the following signature: `int foo(Class< A> classz);`

Now I want this method implementation to return the value if the static field `f`, from the class represented by `classz`; subclasses of `A` may have different values. I don't want to use reflection (and neither the new jdk7 invoke.* features). For now, I have this solution that works, but isn't good, since it instanciates an object (which should not be necessary) and it generate a warning by accessing a static field from an instance:

```
int foo(Class< A> classz) throws [don't matter] {
    return classz.newInstance().f;
}
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance?

PS: Don't know how to type `Class< ?>` without the space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do or why you're passing in a class at all - it looks like you should just need:

```
int foo() {
    return A.f;
}
```

On success, that's what your current code will be returning anyway. Your code is equivalent to:

```
int foo(Class<A> classz) throws ... {
    A ignored = classz.newInstance();
    return A.f;
}
```

It sounds like you're *trying* to use polymorphism with static fields - that's simply not going to work. Static members aren't polymorphic, and neither are fields. If you're declaring extra `f` fields within each subclass, you *would* have to use reflection to get at them, but I advise you to redesign anyway. If you're *not* declaring extra `f` fields within each subclass, then you've only got one field anyway - `B.f` and `C.f` will basically resolve to `A.f` anyway...

Comment: The thing is classes B, C, D can have different values on f. The solution I posted works in the sense that it has this kind of 'polymorphism with static fields'; I mean when you access a static field from an instance it has this 'polymorphism'... (Well, mayble ill try to javap my solution to see how its done in bytecode level)

Comment: @FakeFaker: No, they can't have different values for `f`, unless they're declaring their own variables - in which case you're basically shadowing. It's not a good design and you *will* need to use reflection. And no, it *doesn't* have this sort of polymorphism. For example: `A a = new B(); int x = a.f;` will *always* use `A.f`, not `B.f`. It would be useful if you could clarify whether you really *have* declared `f` in the subclasses - because if you haven't, you've only got a single variable and I suspect you've fooled yourself into thinking you've got one per subclass.

Comment: Hm...No I didn't declared it in subclasses and I have indeed fooled myself into thinking I have one per subclass :) that was stupid, I'll try to rethink my whole problem.. Thanks