# Get static variable from class stored in Class variable

Tags: java

Is there any way this can be done:

```
Class cls = MyClass.class;
int variable = cls.staticVariable;

Class MyClass {
    public static int staticVariable = 5;
}
```

Class cls will always contain a class that has the variable staticVariable, but it won't always be the same class. Hope you understand.

Comment: Why don't you try and see for yourself?

Comment: @AniketThakur Well that doesn't work, I was just for explaining my problem.

Comment: ok did not get your question. Try Reflection APIs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing static field from Class<A> variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019507/accessing-static-field-from-classa-variable)

Comment: This is really error prone. Stay away from such solutions whenever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short working example demonstrating the concept via reflection.

```
public class ReflectionStatic {

    public static int staticVariable = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Class<ReflectionStatic> clazz = ReflectionStatic.class;
        int value = clazz.getField("staticVariable").getInt(null);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only via the reflection API.

```
Field f = cls.getField("staticVariable");
int variable = f.getInt(null);
```

There will be a lot of exceptions for you to catch here.